# Whats the difference between running docker in daemon mode vs systemctl start docker?

Tags: docker, daemon

What is the difference between starting the docker daemon using `dockerd` and `systemctl start docker`.
When would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 5):

A list that is probably not comprehensive:

- You can configure systemd to run docker when your system boots (`systemctl enable docker`).
- If you start the service using systemd, you can ask systemd whether or not it's running (`systemctl status docker`), and the answer is authoritative (compared to running something like `ps | grep dockerd`, which can return false positives).
- If you start the service using systemd, systemd can automatically restart it if it fails.
- When running the service under systemd, output to stdout/stderr is gathered in the system journal so you can find it via `journalctl -u docker`.
- The systemd unit may apply resource limits that improve the behavior of dockerd (e.g., removing the limits on number of files, number of processes, etc)